# Rewrite cond for domain and www.domain letsencrypt

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, rewritecond

I have this virtualhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cv.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/cv/web
    <Directory /var/www/cv/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cv_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cv_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The lines `Rewrite*` have been added by letsencrypt and I checked on google, it seems to be the good way to do it. But when I go to `domain.com` it doesn't redirect me to `https://example.com` (it loads the 000-default.conf). Nevertheless it is redirecting me to `https://www.example.com` when I go on `www.example.com`

Do you have any idea? I don't know how to debug this. The logs are confirming what I am saying, the cv_access.log does not print any request when I go on `domain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Here, the `%{SERVER_NAME}` variable depends on the [`UseCanonicalName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname), by default set `Off`. Therefore, the variable has the content of `Host:` header, not the one specified in `ServerName`.

> With `UseCanonicalName On` Apache httpd will use the hostname and port
>   specified in the `ServerName` directive to construct the canonical name
>   for the server.
>
> With `UseCanonicalName Off` Apache httpd will form self-referential URLs
>   using the hostname and port **supplied by the client** if any are supplied
>   (otherwise it will use the canonical name, as defined above).

If you prefer to keep using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this redirection, you have two options:

1. Set `UseCanonicalName On`.
2. Use the desired hostname directly in your rule, e.g.

   ```
   RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
   ```

However, you are over-complicating things, as you could do the same without mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here, the the [`Redirect` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) comes from mod_alias, and you don't need `DocumentRoot` etc.

Comment: I am afraid that the `UseCanonicalName On` doesn't work. Or do I have to hardcode the hostname in my rule plus the canonical name?

Comment: The last example is way superior to any mod_rewrite solutions. Use it. You only need those five lines!

Comment: I think the problem comes from somewhere else, it doesn't work either. Sorry :/

Comment: Have you actually enabled the site as it's in `sites-available`? The `a2ensite` helps with that. Maybe the `www` is configured somewhere else, thus working.

Comment: I have checked by executing `grep 'www\.' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*` but there is only results for `cv.conf` and `cv-le-ssl.conf` and I have checked that the Virtualhost is enabled :/